# cannot capture the struct value inside of the kernal function

Tags: c++, lambda, intel-oneapi, sycl, dpc++

It is so strange and I am struggling with this problem for the whole week. I just want to use the variable which is defined inside of the struct constructor, but fail to do that. The simple code is here:

```
#include <CL/sycl.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ghost 3
using namespace cl::sycl;

struct test
{
    int ls[3];
    queue Q{};
    test()
    {
        ls[0] = ghost;
        ls[1] = ghost;
        ls[2] = ghost;
    }
    void calculate();
};

void test::calculate()
{
    size_t lx = 10;
    size_t ly = 10;

    auto abc = Q.submit([&](handler &h)
                        {
        sycl::stream out(1024, 256, h);
        h.parallel_for(range{lx, ly}, [=, lsq = this->ls](id<2> idx)
                       { out << "this is id1" << lsq[1] << "\n"; }); });
}

int main()
{
    test t1;
    t1.calculate();
    return 0;
}
```

Someone from the DPC++ community told me this method to capture this pointer, but I don't why it does not work well.

Comment: You must capture `this`. Think of lambdas as a global function. How does it know about `this` if you don’t transfer it somehow?

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: I now change the lambda function to '''h.parallel_for(range{lx, ly}, [=, ptr=this](id<2> idx)''' and use '''ptr->ls[0]''', it still does not work.

Comment: `[&, this]` and inside lambda instead of `this->member` use `member`. [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)

Comment: auto abc = Q.submit([&, this](handler &h)
                        {
        sycl::stream out(1024, 256, h);
        h.parallel_for(range{lx, ly}, [=,lsq=ls](id<2> idx), and does not work

Comment: “does not work” is too vague - nobody will be able to help you. Post the error. Why didn’t you capture `this` in the nested lambda?

Comment: h.parallel_for(range{lx, ly}, [&,this](id<2> idx)
                       { out << "this is id1" << ls[1] << "\n"; }); });, When I try this and then I got: sycl::stream &' cannot be used as the type of a kernel parameter

Comment: If I change [&,this] to [=,this], I got error:PI CUDA ERROR:
 Value:           700
 Name:            CUDA_ERROR_ILLEGAL_ADDRESS
 Description:     an illegal memory access was encountered
 Function:        cuda_piEnqueueMemBufferRea

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244912/discussion-between-mac-cchiatooo-and-zdf).

Comment: The errors you get are not related to lambda usage. I don’t have time for chatting; sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [4.12.4. Rules for parameter passing to kernels](https://www.khronos.org/registry/SYCL/specs/sycl-2020/html/sycl-2020.html#sec:kernel.parameter.passing) from [SYCL 2020 Specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/SYCL/specs/sycl-2020/html/sycl-2020.html) the array of scalar values can be passed as a kernel parameter. But the problem is in the capturing of struct member:

```
[lsq = this->ls]
```

is equivalent to

```
auto lsq = this->ls;
```

In this case, the type of `lsq` is `int*` and it will contain the address of `test::ls` in the host memory. The access to the elements of the array in the kernel will lead to the undefined behavior.

There are two possible solutions here:

##### Solution 1

Create a local references to the `test::ls` and pass it to the kernel by value:

```
void test::calculate() {
    size_t lx = 10;
    size_t ly = 10;

    auto abc = Q.submit([&](handler &h) {
        sycl::stream out(1024, 256, h);
        auto& lsq = this->ls;
        h.parallel_for(range{lx, ly}, [=](id<2> idx) {
            out << "this is id1: " << lsq[1] << "\n"; 
        });
    });
}
```

In this case, the captured variable (`lsq`) will have `int[3]` type and will be correctly initialized in the kernel.

##### Solution 2

Use `std::array` or `sycl::marray` instead of C array:

```
#define ghost 3
using namespace cl::sycl;

struct test {
    marray<int, 3> ls;
    queue Q;
    test() {
        ls[0] = ls[1] = ls[2] = ghost;
    }

    void calculate() {
        size_t lx = 10;
        size_t ly = 10;

        auto abc = Q.submit([&](handler& h) {
            sycl::stream out(1024, 256, h);
            h.parallel_for(range{ lx, ly }, [=, lsq = this->ls](id<2> idx) {
                out << "this is id1: " << lsq[1] << "\n";
            });
        });
    }
};
```